# PendingIntent Bundle arguments not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for push notifications. In message received method recd I am creating a notification along with pending intent to to open the detail screen. Here is the class for receiving messages:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.BundleCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.i3techs.mtricks.HomeActivity;
import com.i3techs.mtricks.R;

    import java.util.Map;

    public class FCMMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            Log.d("Message Received",remoteMessage.getFrom());

            if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0)
            {  Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_ic)
                                .setContentTitle(data.get("title"))
                                .setContentText(data.get("excerpt"));
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                Bundle arguments= new Bundle();
                arguments.putBoolean("trickDetail",true);
                arguments.putInt("id",new Integer(data.get("id")));
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,arguments
                        );

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(5, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the onCreate code for HomeActivity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        sessionManager= SessionManager.getInstance(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        layoutDrawer.addDrawerListener(this);
        initializeElements();
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("trickDetail")){
                getDetails();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get bundled arguments from savedInstance without any success. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the `Bundle` to your `Intent`:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putBoolean("trickDetail", true);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtras(arguments);
```

To fetch the `Bundle` in your `Activity` you need to call `getIntent()`:

```
if (getIntent.getBooleanExtra("trickDetail", false)) {
    getDetails();
}
```

`savedInstanceState` is the `Bundle` the Android OS saves before destroying the `Activity` (to reclaim resources for example).

Comment: Thank you, Let me try and I will let you know the results.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.